# Assembly storing string as array changes/deforms every variable after it

Tags: arrays, assembly, emu8086

My program needed a simple text interface. I saved each option's text in a separate variable like this

```
op1 db "enter 1 for option 1$"
op2 db "enter 2 for option 2$"
```

Then I had trouble looping and reading each so I tried saving everything in one array of strings and including linebreaks and carriage returns in the array which looked like this

```
choices db "Enter 1 for sum",010,013,"Enter 2 for sub",010,013,"Enter 3 for mul",010,013,"$"
```

It works fine the first time but as the program goes on and it gets printed again random characters in the text start changing. Even other string variables were being changed until I declared them before the one with the embedded linebreaks, so why does this happen? is there a better way of doing this?  The picture below is what it looks like when it breaks

Edit: It begins changing after int21 with code 09 finishes

[image]

Comment: Use a debugger, single step the program, keep an eye on the string data in memory and notice what instruction changes it.

Comment: I did. it changes after int21 finishes, ill add that to the question

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find what exactly was causing the issue, and it was not how I stored the string. I have a label called 'options' which prints the string

```
options:
mov si, offset choices
mov cx, 1

mov dx, si
mov ah, 9
int 21h

jmp ask
;ret options
```

Originally I had used "ret opions" to print then continue executing where options is called but after playing around with prints for a bit I found that it was what caused the issue, so I switched it to jmp and changed the structure a bit and now it works fine. I don't know what exactly ret messed up but that is how I solved it, and a classmate who was having the same issue said he used org 100h before declaration and it worked for him

Comment: `retn imm16` (or `ret imm16` for some assemblers) [is for popping additional things off the stack](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insRET). Use a plain `retn` (or `ret`), which is the equivalent to `retn 0` (or `ret 0`) to return to after a `call` instruction. Presumably your `ret options` mistake caused the stack to eventually overwrite parts of your strings.

Comment: yup just `ret` worked fine, thanks!